# How to use task or parallel invoke to get translated results in right order?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

```
private string trdoc(string str)
{
    var listOfActions = new List<Action>();

    string alltrdoc = "";
    string doc = str;
    var alldoc = doc.Split('\n');
    foreach(string tt in alldoc)
    {
        //alltrdoc = alltrdoc + translate(tt) + '\n';//I can get the translated sentences in order but it's not multithread so it is slow.

        listOfActions.Add(() => alltrdoc = alltrdoc + translate(tt) + '\n');//I can't get the translated sentences in order.

    }
    int paral = 4;
    if (paral <= 0) { paral = 4; }
    var options = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = paral };
    Parallel.Invoke(options, listOfActions.ToArray());

    saveposcdic();

    return alltrdoc;
}
```

`translate(tt)` should produce translated string.

I've been trying to make a translator. I came across this problem.

If I use the code without, task or parallel.invoke, then I get the document translated in the right order. However if I run the parallel.invoke like above, I will get the sentences in messed up order.

How can I get the translated documents in the right order using task or parallel.invoke?

I thought about adding the translated sentences in the list with numbers then sort the list when all tasks are completed then split the sentences and rearrange them but I think there has got to be a better way.

Code below works but it's not parallel.

```
private string trdoc(string str)
{
   string alltrdoc = "";
   string doc = str;
   var alldoc = doc.Split('\n');

   Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
   foreach (string tt in alldoc)
   {
    alltrdoc = alltrdoc + translate(tt) + '\n';
   }
   });

   t.Wait();

   saveposcdic();

   return alltrdoc;
}
```

Comment: You have the original lines in an array, you could make a result array and let the task put the result in the position you got it from. Or maybe `Parallel.For` would also work and make it even easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enigmativity is right. You need to work cautiously with parallelism.
You may delegete it to linq.

```
var translatedStrings = alldoc
    .AsParallel()
    .WithDegreeOfParallelism(paral)
    .AsOrdered()
    .Select(tt => translate(tt));

var alltrdoc = string.Join("\n", translatedStrings);
```

Here there are two key methods:
[`AsParallel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413602%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which makes `select` executes parallel and [`AsOrdered`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413357(v=vs.110).aspx) which will keep original order of lines.

Your second `trdoc` implementation isn't parallel because you put all the work in one task. It's like running `Parallel.Invoke` with only one `Action`

Comment: I had forgotten about `.AsOrdered()`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you're not capturing the loop variable in your closure. Try changing your loop to be like this:

```
foreach (string tt in alldoc)
{
    string local_tt = tt;
    listOfActions.Add(() => alltrdoc = alltrdoc + translate(local_tt) + '\n');
}
```

The other issue you have is that you're trying to update the single value of `alltrdoc` using multiple threads. It's not going to work like that. You really should consider refactoring this code.

You're better off writing your entire method like this:

```
private string trdoc(string str)
{
    return String.Join(Environment.NewLine, str.Split('\n').AsParallel().Select(x => translate(x)));
}
```

Comment: I don't know why but it still gives translated sentences in wrong order. Still trying to figure out why.

Comment: @user1785594 - Did you try my replacement for your `trdoc` method?

Comment: Yes. Both of them, but it didn't work. I don't know why.

Comment: @user1785594 - How long does a call to `translate` take? And is the code thread-safe? Can you post the code?

Comment: It's in the form1.cs included in the zip file from the mega link. Program itself is far from complete. It uses nuget package mecab for japanese part of speech tagging.

Answer (score 0):

```
private string trdoc(string str)
{
    var alldoc = str.Split('\n');            
    string[] alltrdoc1 = new string[alldoc.Length];

    Parallel.For(0, alldoc.Length,
    index => {

        alltrdoc1[index] = translate(alldoc[index]);

    });

    string alltrdoc = string.Join("\n", alltrdoc1);

    saveposcdic();

    return alltrdoc;
}
```

I've got it working with this code. All the sentences are showing in the right order. I still don't know why Enigmativity's answer didn't work as intended.